# HTML Table with 5 columns and 25 rows (using loops) PHP

Tags: php, html, post, html-table

the table looks like this

ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
ProductID | ProductPrice | Discount% | ShippingOption | PaymentType
...25 ROWS

And the id for each column in HTML are:
ProductID_1, ProductID_2, ...3,4,5, ... until 25

The requirement is NOT TO CHANGE HTML Code!

How can I manage the table programmatic way by using loops instead of typing each column and row?

This is my idea which does not work properly:
`for ($i = 1; $i < 26, $i++) {   $productIDs = $_POST['ProductID_' . $i];   };`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's working for my side

```
<?php
   for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++)
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      for ($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
      {
         echo "<td>$i * $j = ".$i*$j."</td>";
      }
   echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> for ($i = 1; $i < 26, $i++) {   $productIDs = $*POST['ProductID*' .
> $i];   };

If you need to have an array of posted products at server side:

```
$postedProducts = [];
for ($i = 1; $i < 26; $i++) {
    $currProductID = "ProductID_$i";
    if (isset($_POST[$currProductID])) {
        $postedProducts[] = $_POST[$currProductID];
    }
}
```

Though, i don't understand why you need to read from `$_POST`. Normally, a product having an id appeared in user input is used in edit or selection operations.

If really there is any data posting, and it is for the sake of checking selected products, it is sufficient to check if an specific product id is posted: `$selectedProductIDs[] = $i;` in the `if` block.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code. this code is definitely working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table using php</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ProductID</th><th>ProductPrice</th><th>Discount%</th><th>ShippingOption</th><th>PaymentType</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $tableStr = "";
                for($rows=1;$rows<=25;$rows++)
                {
                    $tableStr += "<tr>";                    
                    $tableStr += "<td>".$_POST['ProductID_'.$rows]."</td>"; 
                    $tableStr += "<td>".$_POST['ProductPrice_'.$rows]."</td>";  
                    $tableStr += "<td>".$_POST['Discount_'.$rows]."</td>";  
                    $tableStr += "<td>".$_POST['ShippingOption_'.$rows]."</td>";
                    $tableStr += "<td>".$_POST['PaymentType_'.$rows]."</td>";       
                    $tableStr += "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```